# Why -ing was used in this sentence?

Tags: gerunds

Why *-ing* was used in **meet** and **taste** words in the sentence bellow?

> I love meeting new people and tasting different foods

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more detail to your question. Where does this sentence come from? Why do _you_ think the gerund is used here? Tell us what research you have done; that will help us to provide a useful answer. If you don't add anything to the question, it might be closed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb love can take either a to-infinitive or an -ing form.

I love to meet new people and (to) taste different foods = I love meeting new peope and tasting different foods.